# Eigenvalues of a complex $4 \times 4$ Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A\in \mathbb{C}^{4×4}$. We are given the equation

$$A^{4}+12A^{2}=6A^{3}+8A$$

and

$$\textrm{rank}(A)=2\cdot\textrm{rank}(A-2I_{4})=4$$

I already found out that $2$ is an Eigenvalue, but how do I determine the other ones ? I'm mainly looking for hints.

Comment: Is it $\textrm{rank}(A)=2\times\textrm{rank}(A-2I_{4})=4$ or $\textrm{rank}(A)=2$ and $\textrm{rank}(A-2I_{4})=4$?

Comment: Your last equality cannot be , since it is clear zero is one of the eigenvalues and thus $\;A\;$ cannot have full rank (in this case, full rank$\,=4\,$ )...or directly one can see $\;A\;$ cannot be invertible as it is a zero divisor...

Comment: The first one, assuming that with $×$ you mean the same as $\cdot$

Comment: It's a homework problem thats formulated exactly like I posted it

Comment: @ChristianSinger Then the problem is exactly wrong.

Comment: I see your point. Do you think I should delete this question or keep it because the info was nonetheless helpful to me in some way (and maybe for others aswell)

Comment: @ChristianSinger Keep it, by all means! As you say, even as the question seems to be wrong, both comments and answers help fpr better understanding certain features.

Comment: Solutions exist, as mechanodroid's answer shows. The comments here seem to confuse the given polynomial with the characteristic polynomial, even though the implication is merely that it the given polynomial has the minimal polynomial of $A$ as a factor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The polynomial $x^4-6x^3+12x^2-8x = x(x-2)^3$ annihilates the matrix $A$ so $\sigma(A) \subseteq \{0,2\}$.

If $\sigma(A) = \{0\}$ then $\operatorname{rank}(A-2I) = 4$ so $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2\operatorname{rank}(A-2I) = 8 > 4$ which is a contradiction.

Assume $\sigma(A) = \{0,2\}$.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 0$ then $A = 0$ so $\sigma(A) = \{0\}$, a contradiction.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 2$ then $\operatorname{rank}(A-2I) = 1$ so $$\operatorname{null}(A) + \operatorname{null}(A - 2I) = 2 + 3 = 5 > 4$$

which is a contradiction.

If $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 4$, then $0 \notin \sigma(A)$, a contradiction.

Therefore, the only option is $\sigma(A) = \{2\}$, which implies $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 4$ and $\operatorname{rank}(A-2I) = 2$. An example of such a matrix is

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Could you briefly explain what $\sigma(A)$ is ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger The spectrum i.e. the set of all eigenvalues of $A$.

Comment: And how exactly does the polynomial anihilate the Maxtrix ?

Comment: @ChristianSinger It just means that $A^4-6A^3+12A^2-8A = 0$. If a polynomial $p$ annihilates a matrix (i.e. $p(A) = 0$), then the minimal polynomial of $A$ divides $p$, so $$\sigma(A) = \{\text{ zeros of } m_A\} \subseteq \{\text{ zeros of } p\}$$

Comment: Thanks, we haven't introduced minimal polynomials yet but I get the idea.

Comment: @ChristianSinger You can also see it like this: assume $p(A) = 0$ and take an eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$. There exists $x \ne 0$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$. Then $$0 = p(A)x = p(\lambda)x \implies p(\lambda) = 0$$
so $\lambda$ is necessarily a zero of $p$.

Comment: The given example Jordan form for $A$ has minimal polynomial $(x-2)^3$. Another dissimilar example would be $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix}2&1&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ with minimal polynomial $(x-2)^2$.

Comment: @ccorn Yes, and those two are the only possibilities for the Jordan form of $A$ because $\operatorname{null}(A-2I) = 2$ implies that there are exactly two Jordan blocks for the eigenvalue $2$ (so they can be of sizes $3$ and $1$, or of sizes $2$ and $2$).